# Strange hover styling in a dropdown

Tags: html, css

Back again with an issue that has been plaguing me for a few days now. I've searched around to see if this is just a Bootstrap issue or something in the CSS itself and haven't found much. I could be missing something, but when I inspect the page to try and select the dropdown menu itself, I can't seem to get the dropdown to activate, so I haven't found a fix.

To keep it simple, on the [Apprenace page](http://www.apprenace.com) , there's a dropdown effect when you hover on About Apprenace in the nav bar. When that hover happens, the title gets a little highlight color change, but when you go down into the items in the dropdown, that hover gets interrupted by the link hover change. I'm assuming that link hover is being overridden by something, but I'm not sure what. I am guessing this is an easy fix that I'm just overlooking by staring at this for too long.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

EDIT:

Here is the only CSS code example I've been able to mess around with that seems to actively respond to the menu in terms of styling. Everything else was changing other aspects. I feel like the issue is somewhere in here.

```
  #menu-home-menu li.menu-item {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
text-align: right;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}

#menu-home-menu li.menu-item a {
 padding: 0 0 !important;
}

#menu-home-menu li.menu-item:hover a {
 color: #ffb300 !important;
}
```

Removing the color styling helps somewhat, because that white box doesn't appear when hovering over the links that turn green, however, then the entire nav bar loses that hover color shift.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for people to help you better you should provide the relevant code you have tried so far. So i would add your menu code and the CSS you are using that pertains to that menu item.

Comment: >When that hover happens, the title gets a little highlight color change, but when you go down into the items in the dropdown, that hover gets interrupted by the link hover change. -- Not able to replicate this in chrome.

Comment: Please add a meaningful code example here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You have a color definition for a tags set to !important in green.scss:88. But i agree with the comment above that it is best to add code here so people can learn.

Comment: Sorry y'all, I went ahead and added the code for that particular area that I had been messing with.